# foreachRDD sometimes takes too long between batches

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I have a problem, we are using Kafka and spark.

```scala
val ssc = new StreamingContext(conf, Seconds(10))
val messages = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent, ConsumerStrategies.Subscribe[K, V](config.topics, scala.collection.Map[String, Object](kafkaParams.toSeq: _*), offsetRange)))
messages.foreachRDD {(rdd, time) => ...}
```

It works well, but sometimes new batch begins to start after about 10 minutes after previous one. Times are measured by log messages.

Why is that happening?

Comment: Why not use Structured Streaming?

Comment: @OneCricketeer legacy code

Comment: Alright, so what happens exactly "for each RDD"? Something is blocking processing causing a long delay in the "next RDD"? How fast is the producer sending data into the topic? (Maybe the Spark consumer is waiting for N records in the topic before reading the next batch)

Comment: @OneCricketeer for each rdd some metrics are calculated(count, size etc) and inserted to cassandra. However the point is that between log message at the very end of foreachRDD and log message at start of next batch there are 10 minutes passed. 
Regarding wait N records, when I use Seconds(10) it should(and it does in tests in my laptop) to create a batch every 10 seconds, even if it is an empty rdd.

Comment: Is it possible your Spark cluster is slowed down by other executors from other submissions? Where your local laptop is not?

Comment: It is, but this is the only job having such problem, and there are few others working good.

Comment: Hi @OneCricketeer, 
i`ve found the reason, it was due to https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-12890

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I`ve found the reason, it was due to issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-12890